# Cannot find a mail in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook

When searching for mail with my keywords, mail which haven't been moved into a folder can be found in the list, while the ones I have moved into a folder cannot be found. Trying to use `all outlook items` is not helpful either.

Do you have the same issue like me? What is the workaround?

Comment: Are you keeping them in the same PST file or are they moved to a different physical location?

Comment: All are in the same .pst file